# Mongoosastic search immediatly after saving to mongoose

Tags: mongoose, mongoosastic

I have an api endpoint for posting data to mongoose.
I try to perform a search immediately after and i get 0 results. the code:

```
newSchema.save((err) => { 
    if (err) reject(new Error(err));

    newSchema.on('es-indexed', (err, res) => {
        Schema.search(query, function (err, results) {
            resolve(results);
        });
    });
});
```

My **hits** return empty.
If i surround `Schema.search` with a timeout of **1000ms** i get the results i hoped for.

I don't wanna use this timeout workaround. Anybody have a suggestion?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

for anyone who is interested, i found out that `mongodb` doesn't have a thing called "locking", so if you post parallel writes to the database you'd end up with elastic go out of sync.

for now i use `kue` to manage tasks and lock the database until `es-indexed` is fired.

(i might have missed something if anyone could shed light on this)